# .htaccess 403 Forbidden if url contains directory with another htaccess file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I have a `.htaccess` file in website root with the following rules :

```
Options -MultiViews
Options All -Indexes

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA]
```

And another `.htaccess` file in a sub-directory (let's call it `Foo`) :

```
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from all

<files ~ "\.(js|jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|css)">
    Allow from all
</files>
```

When I access for example : `/test/test/test` it normally redirects me to `index.php`, but when I my URI starts with existing directory it throws 403 error, ex : `/Foo/test/test/test` => 403 Error

So my question is : **How to make it to redirect to `index.php` even if it matches an existing sub-directory?**

*Note : Sub-Directoy must contain a .htaccess file to disallow direct access to files in it.*

Another Question : **How to make all requests (even existing files and directories) except (images, css, js) to go to `index.php?url=$1`?** When i remove `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` it redirects to `index.php?url=index.php&url=$1` or gives `Internal Error`

Comment: if you override the .htaccess in a specific dir, that .htaccess is now responsible for letting through "legal" routes. So if you have 100 dirs each with their own .htaccess file, you are 100 x responsible for making those .htaccess files allow the base routing you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep your root .htaccess as this:

```
Options All -Indexes -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(^/index\.php|\.(js|jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|css))$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /index.php?url=%1 [QSA,L]
```

Keep your `/Foo/.htaccess` as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteOptions Inherit

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule !\.(js|jpe?g|png|gif|bmp|css)$ - [F,NC]
```

- `RewriteOptions Inherit` will inherit rules from parent .htaccess
- Instead of `allow/deny` better to use `mod_rewrite` for finer control here

Comment: it doesn't work without RewriteBase, but with it gives wrong results

Comment: Provide more details as `it gives wrong results` doesn't tell me anything.

Comment: oh amazing! sorry, maybe I did something wrong, or you edited it after I tested it, but now it works great! The only thing is that when I enter only sub-dir name like /Foo it shows 403 error, for any other combination like /Foo/test it works

Comment: Didn't noticed that you added condition from my newer question, now having separated .htaccess files in sub-dirs is useless, removed it from sub-dir and now everything works great!