# .htaccess doubles query string parameter

Tags: php, .htaccess

I am trying to redirect all requests except images, css, javascript to my `index.php` from root directory, so user can not access other files like `.php` directly.

I have following rules in my `.htaccess` file in my website's root directory :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(css|js|png|jpe?g|gif|bmp|txt)$

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?url=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

In index.php I wrote `print_r($_SERVER)` and when I access for example `/test` under `[QUERY_STRING]` it shows something I don't understand  :

```
array(
..
[QUERY_STRING] => url=index.php&url=test
..
)
```

My questions are : **Why is this happening?** and **Does this affect website performance?**

*Note : If I add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` it shows only `url=test`, but this allows direct access to files, so a removed this condition.*

Comment: This tells that you have two redirects. /test to index.php?url=test and than the second for index.php to the one that you have.

Comment: @Cheery is it possible to have only one redirect?

Comment: Did you try to add the condition not to redirect requests of index.php ? This is, actually, how `!-f` works - it does not redirect as file exists.

Comment: @Cheery .. but where?

Comment: Additional RewriteCond, somebody already wrote it in the answer

Comment: @John: [I am wondering if you're even reading answers to your questions.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26168384/548225)

Answer (score 0):

As Cheery points out in the comments, Apache is performing multiple rewrites. You should add `index.php` to the list of things the rewrite engine should leave alone:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !index\.php$
```

Comment: tried to add it before/after existing condition, but still same result => [QUERY_STRING] => url=index.php&url=foo

Comment: @John Edited, try it again?